# How can I create formatted Text in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I create formatted Text in Windows Phone 7? I see that the `RichTextBox` doesn't work here. While I won't get a answer I write a method for this. If someone know a easier way write me. Thanks.

Comment: RichTextBoth should work in Mango (7.1)

Answer (score 2):

Without using the `RichTextBox` you are limited to using [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) flow elements inside a TextBlock, such as this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Foreground="Blue" Content="blue text" />
    <Run Foreground="Red" Background="Yellow" Content="red on yellow" />
    <Run FontStyle="Bold" Background="Yellow" Content="bold yellow text" />
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

A few more notes about the RichTextBox in WP7.1 / Mango - I believe that for now, it's still a read only control and is meant for developers intending to display rich text from external sources, and you'll still need to manually create all the tags yourself (ie <Run>, <Paragraph>, <Hyperlink>)

Take a look at this great article for a more detailed rundown: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control